# Can't getting data from API using retrofit2

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, retrofit2

help me for this issue please, I want to get data from API

```
{
"status": true,
"data": [
    {
        "id_pelanggan": "456",
        "nama_pelanggan": "ahmad",
        "alamat": "taliwang"
    },
    {
        "id_pelanggan": "457",
        "nama_pelanggan": "ahmad",
        "alamat": "taliwang"
    }
]}
```

this is my API object for setup for dynamic class, retrofit2 and gson

```
object Api {
    private val BASE_URL: String = BuildConfig.API_SRAPP
    private var gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
    private val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

    fun <T>service(java: Class<T>): T{
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(httpClient.build())
            .build()
        return retrofit.create(java)
    }
}
```

this is my class BaseRespon for handle all data from API and with dynamic class

```
data class BaseResponse<T>(
    val status: Boolean,
    val data: T?
)
```

this is my class Customer

```
data class Customer (
    @SerializedName("id_pelanggan")
    @Expose
    val idPelanggan: String,
    @SerializedName("nama_pelanggan")
    @Expose
    val namaPelanggan: String,
    @SerializedName("alamat")
    @Expose
    val alamat: String
)
```

this is my API service

```
interface CustomerServices {

    @GET("customer")
    fun getAllCustomer(@Header("Authorization") auth: String): Call<BaseResponse<ArrayList<Customer>>>

    @GET("customer")
    fun getCustomerbyID(@Header("Authorization") auth: String, @Query("id") id: String): Call<BaseResponse<Customer>>

}
```

and this is my class for using API

```
class CustomerPresenter {

    fun loadAllCustomer(){
        apiCustomer.getAllCustomer(OfflineHelper.getToken())
            .enqueue(object : Callback<BaseResponse<ArrayList<Customer>>>{
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<BaseResponse<ArrayList<Customer>>>, t: Throwable) {
                    Log.e("allCustomer", "${t.message}")
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<BaseResponse<ArrayList<Customer>>>,
                    response: Response<BaseResponse<ArrayList<Customer>>>
                ) {
                    saveLocalCustomer(response.body())
                }
            })
    }

    fun saveLocalCustomer(data: BaseResponse<ArrayList<Customer>>?){
        Log.w("loadedAll", "${data?.status}")
    }
```

and I have log failure in loadAllCustomer

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 2 column 1 path $
```

I don't understand why it's failure, my endpoint is not typo, and I have tested it on postman

Comment: can you add your error with question?

Comment: in the body response, i get null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `List` as your return type for the data field. try this:

```
data class BaseResponseList<T>(
    val status: Boolean,
    val data: List<T>?
)
```

and then using `BaseResponseList` in your call as following:

```
@GET("customer") 
fun getAllCustomer(@Header("Authorization") auth: String): Call<BaseResponseList<Customer>>
```

Use `BaseResponseList` for any endpoint that returns a `List`, and `BaseResponse` for Objects

Answer (score 0):

Update your response class and api interface like below

```
data class BaseResponse(
    val status: Boolean,
    val data: List<Customer>?
)

 interface CustomerServices {

    @GET("customer")
    fun getAllCustomer(@Header("Authorization") auth: String): Call<BaseResponse>

    @GET("customer")
    fun getCustomerbyID(@Header("Authorization") auth: String, @Query("id") id: String): Call<Customer>

}
```

Comment: have you added content type and accept header for json?

Answer (score 0):

your model not same with you object json

Comment: so how to repair my code? because I didn't see any mistake in my model